# Why is my Datagram Packet response incomplete?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, udp, datagram

I'm trying to build an Android app to perform UDP requests. However, whenever I try to receive the response, the last four characters in the response string are missing. The response should be 38 bytes long.

I've tried specifying what encoding to use and it didn't make much difference.

```java
private void updateState() {
    final byte[] msg = hexStringToBytes("24000034...");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress bulbAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
                if (!socket.getBroadcast()) socket.setBroadcast(true);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length, bulbAddress, 56700);
                socket.send(packet);
                DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length, bulbAddress, 56700);
                socket.receive(packet1);

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
                String out = new String(packet1.getData(), packet1.getOffset(), packet1.getLength());

                textView.setText(toHex(out));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private static byte[] hexStringToBytes(String input) {
    input = input.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
    int n = input.length() / 2;
    byte[] output = new byte[n];
    int l = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        char c = input.charAt(l++);
        byte b = (byte) ((c >= 'a' ? (c - 'a' + 10) : (c - '0')) << 4);
        c = input.charAt(l++);
        b |= (byte) (c >= 'a' ? (c - 'a' + 10) : (c - '0'));
        output[k] = b;
    }
    return output;
}

public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes()));
}
```

I expect the last four characters to be present and either FF FF or 00 00.

Comment: UDP doesn't drop parts of datagrams. If those bytes were sent they will be received. How do you know they were sent?

Comment: Hi @user207421, I've tried sending the same message using Packet Sender and I got the last 4 characters outputted. I've tried this on desktop and on the device itself.

Comment: You should not convert the data to a String and back to bytes. Just pass the actual bytes and length direct to `toHex()`. String is not a container for binary data.

Comment: Hi @user207421, I think I've found the problem, I needed to use a new byte array without values of the new length of 28 bytes instead of using the one with only 26 bytes and pass that into packet1. At some point I completely blanked on the fact the first packet is two bytes smaller than the response. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the problem, I needed to use a new byte array without values of the new length of 28 bytes instead of using the one with only 26 bytes and pass that into packet1. At some point I completely blanked on the fact the first packet is two bytes smaller than the response.